# Android Intent ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE with multiple images share in Twitter not working

Tags: android-intent, twitter, android-twitter

I'm trying to share some text and 2 images in Twitter via Android Native Intent share. I tried with the below code.

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(new File("LOCATION OF THE FILE"));
Uri u2 = Uri.fromFile(new File("LOCATION OF THE FILE"));
uris.add(u1);
uris.add(u2);

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
share.setType("*/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share Text");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
share.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
context.startActivity(share);
```

with the above code i cannot able to attach the two images. **But the same code works for the Email Share.** I could able to attach two images to the email client with no issues. **But with twitter i'm facing problem**.

**My summary of questions:**
When i try to attach single image it works fine. But not when attaching more than 1 comes the problem.

1. Does twitter support uploading more than two images at the time through native intent share?
2. When using **"Intent.ACTION_SEND"** - Twitter app appears for sharing. But when i use **"Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE"** - Twitter app is not listed.
3. I have latest version of Twitter Official App installed in my device.
4. My Device running Android 5.1. But even tried with 4.2 problem exists.
5. When using **"Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE"** app crashes. Log says **"Activity not found exception"** even though the app is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does twitter support uploading more than two images at the time through native intent share?

> No it does not support Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.

2. When using "Intent.ACTION_SEND" - Twitter app appears for sharing. But when i use "Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE" - Twitter app is not listed.

> As it doesn't support Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, It will not get listed.

I have latest version of Twitter Official App installed in my device.
My Device running Android 5.1. But even tried with 4.2 problem exists.
When using "Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE" app crashes. Log says "Activity not found exception" even though the app is installed

> Before firing the intent check weather there is any application to
>   handle it, to avoid the crash.

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager()
    .queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
```

Comment: That's sad. Isn't there any workaround? Such as twitter API or so?